# Where can I download oracle 10g software for solaris?

Tags: oracle-10g, solaris

I need 10g RAC software (Solaris 11 SPARC) for an audit.

It's no longer on OTN.
I've opened an SR, but it is taking forever then they gave me the wrong O/S.

Do you know of any other place to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have some 10.2.0.1 installers. The name of the files:

```
$ ls -1 10.2.0.1/*
10.2.0.1/AIX64:
B24442-01_1of3.zip
B24442-01_2of3.zip
B24442-01_3of3.zip
B24443-01_1of4.zip
B24443-01_2of4.zip
B24443-01_3of4.zip
B24443-01_4of4.zip

10.2.0.1/HPUX64:
B24445-01_1of3.zip
B24445-01_2of3.zip
B24445-01_3of3.zip
B24446-01_1of4.zip
B24446-01_2of4.zip
B24446-01_3of4.zip
B24446-01_4of4.zip

10.2.0.1/Linux_x86:
10201_database_linux32.zip

10.2.0.1/Linux_x86-64:
B24792-01_1of5.zip
B24792-01_2of5.zip
B24792-01_3of5.zip
B24792-01_4of5.zip
B24792-01_5of5.zip

10.2.0.1/Solaris_x86-64:
10201_database_solx86_64.zip

10.2.0.1/SPARC64:
B24448-01_1of3.zip
B24448-01_2of3.zip
B24448-01_3of3.zip
B24449-01_1of4.zip
B24449-01_2of4.zip
B24449-01_3of4.zip
B24449-01_4of4.zip

10.2.0.1/Windows_x86:
10201_client_win32.zip
10201_clusterware_win32.zip
10201_companion_win32.zip
10201_database_win32.zip
10201_gateways_win32.zip

10.2.0.1/Windows_x86-64:
102010_win64_x64_client.zip
102010_win64_x64_clusterware.zip
102010_win64_x64_companion.zip
102010_win64_x64_database.zip
```

Using the above information, now you are 1 Google search away from finding what you need. Whether you trust those sources, is up to you.